# Coroutine constantly updating animator transition

Tags: unity, coroutines, animation-states, animator

I have a problem for a while now and I am running out of ideas:
I have a made a coroutine used to implement animations in the attacks, something like this

```cs
private IEnumerator FirstAttack()
    {

        comboCounter = 1;
        myAnimator.SetInteger("comboSequence", comboCounter);
        currentState = PlayerState.attack;
        yield return null;

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(AttackTemplate.SetDuration(0.9f));
        comboCounter = 0;
        myAnimator.SetInteger("comboSequence", comboCounter);

        currentState = PlayerState.walk;

    }
```

This coroutine works perfectly fine. The problem occurs when I try to concatenate this with another coroutine to perform something like a combo sequence; to do so I basically add a while cycle that checks if I am pressing the attack button while there is a time opening for the second attack to connect. The result is this:

```
private IEnumerator FirstAttack() {

        comboCounter = 1;

        myAnimator.SetInteger("comboSequence", comboCounter);

        currentState = PlayerState.attack;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(AttackTemplate.SetDuration(0.6f) - comboTimer);//Problem: if i reduce the time below the animation time of the second animation, the second animation won't go until the end

        StartCoroutine(IntervalCounter());
        comboCounter = 0;
        myAnimator.SetInteger("comboSequence", comboCounter);
        currentState = PlayerState.walk;

    }

    private IEnumerator SecondAttack()
    {

        comboCounter = 2;
        myAnimator.SetInteger("comboSequence", comboCounter);
        currentState = PlayerState.attack;
        yield return null;

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(AttackTemplate.SetDuration(0.9f));
        comboCounter = 0;
        myAnimator.SetInteger("comboSequence", comboCounter);

        currentState = PlayerState.walk;

    }


    private IEnumerator IntervalCounter()
    {
        comboTimer = AttackTemplate.SetComboTimer(0.4f);
        while (comboTimer >= 0)
        {
            Debug.Log(comboTimer);
            comboTimer -= Time.deltaTime;
            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Mouse0))
            {
                Debug.Log("Chained");
                StartCoroutine(SecondAttack());
                yield break;
            }
            yield return null;
        }

    }
```

My problem is that after adding the while loop the transition to the first animation keeps being updated, to be precise the one going from *Any State* to *Basic Attack Tree* in the following image.

[image]

If I press the attack button this transition will be repeated as long as the coroutine working. I tried to wrap around the first two lines in which i set the animator to do nothing if the integer managing the combo sequence, `comboCounter` is already set to 1 (which is the value related to the first attack), like this

```cs
        if (comboCounter != 1)
        {
            comboCounter = 1;
            myAnimator.SetInteger("comboSequence", comboCounter);
        }else if(comboCounter == 1) {

        }
```

But it keeps repeating. I wanted to use something like WaitUntil, but I tried just to put it and having a bool always false, in order to suspend the coroutine indefinitely, but in that period it **keeps updating the animator**. Do you have any ideas why is that? How do I prevent a coroutine from running all the time?

Answer (score 1):

I find that OO and state machines tend to produce spaghetti code and blocks like this can be quite hard to understand. Rewriting it as pseudocode in a functional style, we can architect the flow of states a bit better - An input should trigger the first attack which should trigger waiting for a second attack window which should allow for the combo to continue:

```
        bool canCombo = false;
        void onAttackInput()
        {

            //if we should begin the first attack
            if (comboCounter == 0)
            {
                myAnimator.SetInteger("comboSequence", comboCounter);
                currentState = PlayerState.attack;

                //in 0.6 seconds, will be able to combo
                wait(0.6f, () =>
                 {
                     canCombo = true;
                     //in 0.3 seconds, combo window could be gone
                     wait(0.3f, () =>
                     {
                         //if no combo input happened, reset
                         if (comboCounter == 1)
                         {
                             canCombo = false;
                             comboCounter = 0;
                             myAnimator.SetInteger("comboSequence", comboCounter);
                             currentState = PlayerState.walk;
                         }
                     });

                 });
            }
            //if we should begin the second attack
            if (comboCounter == 1 && canCombo)
            {
                myAnimator.SetInteger("comboSequence", comboCounter);
                currentState = PlayerState.attack;

                //in 0.9 seconds, attack ends
                wait(0.9f, () =>
                {
                    comboCounter = 0;
                    myAnimator.SetInteger("comboSequence", comboCounter);
                    currentState = PlayerState.walk;
                });
            }

            //on any input, check if an input is valid and increment the combo counter
            if (canCombo)
            {
                canCombo = false;
                comboCounter++;
            }
        }
```

But in C# you can't use yield with lambdas ()=>, so this mythical wait() function really needs to be StartCoroutine() and the lambda should be its own function with a yield WaitForSeconds() at the top:

```
        bool canCombo = false;
        private IEnumerator onAttackInput()
        {

            //if we should begin the first attack
            if (comboCounter == 0)
            {
                myAnimator.SetInteger("comboSequence", comboCounter);
                currentState = PlayerState.attack;

                StartCoroutine(FirstAttack());
            }
            //if we should begin the second attack
            if (comboCounter == 1 && canCombo)
            {
                myAnimator.SetInteger("comboSequence", comboCounter);
                currentState = PlayerState.attack;

                StartCoroutine(SecondAttack());
            }

            //check if an input is valid and increment the combo counter
            if (canCombo)
            {
                canCombo = false;
                comboCounter++;
            }
        }
        private IEnumerator FirstAttack()
        {
            //in 0.6 seconds, will be able to combo
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.6f);

            //0.6 seconds later, open the combo window
            canCombo = true;
            StartCoroutine(FirstAttackWindow());
        }
        private IEnumerator FirstAttackWindow()
        {
            //in 0.3 seconds, end the combo window
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.3f);

            //0.3 seconds later, reset if not in next attack
            if (comboCounter == 1)
            {
                canCombo = false;
                comboCounter = 0;
                myAnimator.SetInteger("comboSequence", comboCounter);
                currentState = PlayerState.walk;
            }
        }

        private IEnumerator SecondAttack()
        {
            //in 0.9 seconds, attack ends
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.9f);

            //0.9 seconds later
            comboCounter = 0;
            myAnimator.SetInteger("comboSequence", comboCounter);
            currentState = PlayerState.walk;

        }
```

Comparing the two sets of code, it looks like your analysis of if(comboCounter != 1) is correct and it's not stopping the rest of the function(including comboCounter = 0;) from happening. You can't really stop coroutines indefinitely, it's better to make sure that they only do what they need to do, and run only when needed, instead.